# Bootstrap Input group: add css property to button when focus on Input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I would like to add a css property `background` to the `button` when we focus on the `input` field. I know there is no previous sibling selector exist.

Is there any new solution for this? other than `flex-flow: row-reverse`, `order` & floating items..?

Please see the below snippet:

```css
.form-control:focus ~ .btn {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">Button</button>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and this works

```css
.input-group:focus-within .btn {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Its working.. really great support Sir.

Answer (score 2):

You can involve javascript and listen to `focus` & `blur` events on input field and add `background-color` by setting a `class` on btn and handle that class styles in css

```js
document.querySelector('.form-control').addEventListener('focus', () => {
  document.querySelector('.btn').classList.add('focused')
})

document.querySelector('.form-control').addEventListener('blur', () => {
  document.querySelector('.btn').classList.remove('focused')
})
```

```css
.form-control:focus ~ .btn {
  background: red;
}

.btn.focused {
background: red
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">Button</button>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
</div>
```

Comment: Its great, but I need to mange it with CSS side.. do you have any CSS solution?